# How to Compute for the Transition Probability Matrix F

Tags: probability, matrix, transition-matrix

[image]

this is our homework. I don't understand how to compute for the F matrix...I'm having a hard time understanding this transition probability matrix. Thank you in advance!

Comment: please add 'self-study' tag

Answer (score 2):

The (i,j)'th element of the probability transition matrix is defined as 
P(in state j after one year | in state i now).

I.e. the (i,j) element of the probability transition matrix is the probability of a Markov chain being in state j after one period, given that it is in state i now.  In this example, the period is one year.  The states 0,1,2,3,4 are the values of i and j.  So the probability transition matrix in this case is a 5 by 5 matrix, and each row (i) and column (j) can be considered to be labeled by its corresponding state.

Comment: Hi I still don't quite get it...can you show me how to compute f sub 11? or any element in the matrix? Please.

Comment: f sub 11 is the probability that one year from now, there'll be 1 kid in the household, given that there is 1 kid now. The assumption provided is that there are no deaths.  So f sub 11 is the probability that no kids are born during the year, or perhaps if allowance is made that a kid can become an adult or move out, number of kids born equals number of kids who become adults or move out. But it may be that they want you to not consider kids becoming adults or moving out, in which case f sub 11 would be the probability of a household with 1 kid not having any kids born during the coming year.

Comment: You are showing only the continuation, not the original statement, so I presume sufficient information is provided there to enable computation of the required probabilities.